# Restarting a game

Tags: game-state, screen-management

I'm having trouble restarting a 2D game when the user presses the "New Game" button.

**Structure of my game:**

The game has several 'screens': Opening screen, instructions screen, main game screen, and a game-over screen.

Each screen is an instance of a class: `OpeningScreen` class, `GameScreen` class, etc.

There is a class named `Main`. This class has three roles.

- It's the JFrame (the window) of the program.
- It has the main method - first class to run.
- It has a method that change's screens.

When the program starts, this class runs. When it first runs:

1. Creates a new instance of itself (it's a JFrame-type class).
2. Creates an instance of every 'screen-class'. The constructor of each 'screen-class' takes the instance of Main as an argument: (aka: `GameOverScreen gameOverScreen = new GameOver(this)`).
3. Creates a new JPanel named mainPanel, and adds it to the JFrame. Any screen to be displayed will be contained in this JPanel (The screens are also JPanel-type classes).

**How the changeScreen() method works:**

The signature of changeScreen() is this: `changeScreen(JPanel from, JPanel to)`.

Whenever a screen needs to be changed, the current screen that is displayed calls this method, like so: `main.changeScreen(this, main.InstructionsScreen)`. It removes the previous screen from `mainPanel` and adds the new screen to `mainPanel`. As said, these screens are created when the program launches.

This is the method that changes screens:

```
public void changeScreen(JPanel from, JPanel to){

    mainPanel.remove(from);
    mainPanel.add(to);

    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();

}
```

**My problem:**

After a game is finished, the Game class calls the `changeScreen` method: `main.changeScreen(this, main.GameOverScreen)` .

This replaces the game screen with a game over screen.
Pressing the "New Game" button in the game-over screen, calls `main.changeScreen(this, main.GameScreen)` .

**The problem:** Pressing the "New Game" button in the game-over screen, indeed displays once again the instance of the `Game` class. But this is the old instance, so the game is not restarted. It's already finished.

I tried to do the following changes in `changeScreen()`:

```
public void changeScreen(JPanel from, JPanel to){

    mainPanel.remove(from);

    if(to.equals(gameScreen)){
        gameScreen = null;
        gameScreen = new GameScreen(this);
    }
    mainPanel.add(gameScreen);

    mainPanel.revalidate();
    mainPanel.repaint();

}
```

This should reset the `gameScreen` object.
But this creates a delay of about 10 seconds when pressing the "New Game" button.

What would be a good way of restarting the game?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's an OK way to do it. The way I do is that I have a `ScreenManager` which "*loads*" screens, those screens are implementing the `IScreen` interface and has different methods like `LoadContent`, `UnloadContent` and `Initialize`.

For instance, when I press the PLAY button in the main menu, the `ScreenManager`'s `addScreen` function runs, sets the `oldScreen` variable's value to the `newScreen`'s value(in this example the main menu screen is becoming the `oldScreen`) and creates, loads the new screen whilst "*Unloading*" the previous one. *(Note that I am using a loading screen)*

The when the unloading is done, and the `LoadContent` sets the `ScreenManager`'s state to DONE, the `ScreenManager` is waiting for the user's input (press any key to continue). When it finally gets the input, the `ScreenManager` intializes the `newScreen` and removes the loading graphics.

In my `ScreenManager`, restarting is nothing else but calling the `addScreen` function of my `ScreenManager`.